# C# Invoke JavaScript in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, wpf, windows-phone-8

I am trying to invoke JavaScript method in my `WebBrowser` :

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
webBrowser.LoadCompleted += ((s, r) =>
{
         try
         {
                 object tmp = webBrowser.InvokeScript("GetData");
         }
         catch (Exception exc)
         {
         }
});
```

This is the `HTML` :

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetData ()
    {
        return 50;
    }

</script>
```

But when i invoke the javascript with :

```
object tmp = webBrowser.InvokeScript("GetData");
```

I get `Exception`:

Message:

```
An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006.
```

StakeTrace:

```
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.InvokeScript(String scriptName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript(String scriptName)
   at YouTube.YouTubeExtractor.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExtractVideoById>b__0(Object s, NavigationEventArgs r)
```

Comment: on the topic of Javascript invoke on WebBrowser control, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/27468013/262379

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled` to `true` (it is `false` by default)

Comment: That is not a property for the WPF WebBrowser control.